# How can i get a object from a other function in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two functions projectTimerStart to start the timer and projectTimerStop
i want to use the object which is created in projectTimerStart and i want to end the time when projectTimerStop , and this should be saved in a database

ps: Both the functions are not in class they are normal functions

```
def projectTimerStart(request, slug):
    project_detail = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    b = ProjectTimer(time_started=datetime.now(),
    working_project=project_detail,
    working_freelancer=request.user
    )
    b.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_timer', kwargs= 
           {"slug":slug}))


def projectTimerStop(request,  slug):
    project_detail = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    #i want something here super method or something
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_timer', kwargs=
           {"slug": slug}))
```

## models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):

    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='created')
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, blank=True, related_name='assigned_by')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    hourly_budget = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField(
    Technologies, related_name='technologies_used')
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    request_id = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='requested_by', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.project_title)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_timer_url(self):
        return reverse('project_timer', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def round_datetime(dt):
        minutes = round((dt.minute + float(dt.second) / 60) / 15) * 15 - 
        dt.minute
        return dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes=minutes, seconds=-dt.second)


class ProjectTimer(models.Model):
    time_started = models.DateTimeField()
    time_ended = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    working_project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    working_freelancer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Will each user have only one timer for each project, though?

Comment: no i have made another model to store multiple timespans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of your project objects will have one and only project timer objects, you can add `project_timer = models.OneToOneField(ProjectTimer)` to your `Project` model and access to the project timer by using `project_detail.project_timer`.

If not, you need to know at least one feature of that project_timer in order to fetch it from database. Or you can iterate all of your `ProjectTimer` objects that belongs to that `Project` and select the appropriate one by:

models.py

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    # Some fields
    project_timers = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectTimer)
```

views.py

```py
def projectTimerStop(request,  slug):
    project_detail = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    for pt in project_detail.project_timers.all():
        if pt.some_field == "THIS IS CORRECT TIMER":
            # Here is your project_detail
            print(str(pt))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_timer', kwargs=
           {"slug": slug}))
```

Comment: added my models.py file for more clarity

Comment: You can use ManyToManyField. I've edited my answer. But as I said, you must know at least one unique identifier of the desired ProjectTimer object to obtain it.